# How to covert byte array b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04' to Readable character string "20600" using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting `b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04'` byte array and I am trying to convert it to `206000` but when I use decode("utf8") it's printing `206000` and while returning it returns same byte array `2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04` in string format i.e. `2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04`

I am doing decryption using AES of given encrypted string.

```py
a = b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04'
b = ""
for aa in a:
    print(chr(aa))

print(b)
```

I expect the output of `b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04'` to be `206000`, but the actual output is `2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04`.

Comment: That's not UTF-8 encoding, it's UTF-16LE.  You first need to remove the padding bytes (the four 4's) that were added to make the message a multiple of the AES block size.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your string is of type `utf16`. I did `a.decode('utf16')` and it gave me '206000ЄЄ' as the result. Not sure why these euro came but thought this might aid you to finally reach the goal. I think there is some problem with your utf16 encoding, but I am pretty sure it is utf-16 and this would be the solution. All the best. :)

Comment: The euro signs are from the `0x04` repeated 4 times at the end. I think that is probably padding. And it looks like PKCS padding for a 12 byte message (which this is) will use 4 x 0x04. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.csfb400/pkcspad.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your responses. I temporary solution for this. Because of some extra padding, it was not working. But after removing extra padding it is successfully running now.

```
data= b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04'.decode("utf8")
data= data.replace("\x00","")
data= data.replace("\x04","")
print(data)
```

I know it is the wrong way to solve the problem. But I promise you I will come back with a proper solution.

Thank You,
Hemant Hatankar

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the padding bytes first at the end of the byte array. and then you can use this to convert it into human readable string.
although \x00 represents null so this might help

```
a = b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04'
print("".join( chr(x) for x in a if x != 0x04))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to decode the byte array into a string first:

```
a = b'2\x000\x006\x000\x000\x000\x00\x04\x04\x04\x04'
b = a.decode('utf-8')
for aa in b:
    print(aa)

print(b)
```

Comment: This ain't a 'utf-8' string.